# A Problem Definitions in regards to Classes

Tags: python

```
# This Program generates a class that is aimed at finding the Area and Perimeter
# in a rectangle.

import math

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.width = 2
        self.height = 1

    def getArea(self):
        area = self.width * self.height
        return area

    def getPerimeter(self):
        perimeter = 2 * (self.width + self.height)
        return perimeter

    def setHeight(self, height):
        self.height = height

    def setWidth(self, height):
        self.width = width

def main():
    rectangle1 = Rectangle()
    print("The area of the Rectangle of radius" , Rectangle1.width, Rectangle1.height, "is",\
          Rectangle1.getArea())
main()
```

## The following Code is in Python. So far the only issue I have at the moment is that when I go to run it it says that the name "Rectangle" is not defined. This is in reference to rectangle1 = Rectangle() in which it is assigned to the class and all of the various instances and methods that it has listed above.

## But because of this definition issue, I cant use the Rectangle class's contents. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You got typo in your code replace `Rectangle1` with `rectangle1`..

Comment: Rectangle1 = Rectangle()  <== Should it look something  like this?

Comment: For variable names you should follow PEP8  "names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability." -> https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles

Answer (score 5):

There are so many error in your program.

1. function **init** takes two argument, and you are not providing any argument while creating object `Rectangle()`
2. function `setWidth(self, height)`, and inside function you are using variable `width`.
3. Python is case sensitive, so rectangle is different from Rectangle, In the caller place, Your object name is 'rectangle1', while you are calling it with `Rectangle1`

If you fix these your program should work

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple mistakes. You are calling Rectangle class without height and width (you could also pass them as default parameters).

Your indentation is broken in the class.

You have initialized rectangle1 but calling Rectangle1, hence the additional errors.

```
import math

class Rectangle:
  def __init__(self, height, width):
      self.width = 2
      self.height = 1

  def getArea(self):
      area = self.width * self.height
      return area

  def getPerimeter(self):
      perimeter = 2 * (self.width + self.height)
      return perimeter

  def setHeight(self, height):
      self.height = height

  def setWidth(self, height):
      self.width = width

def main():
    rectangle1 = Rectangle(4,2)
    print("The area of the Rectangle of radius" , rectangle1.width, rectangle1.height, "is",\
          rectangle1.getArea())
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the line that causes the problem is:

```
print("The area of the Rectangle of radius" , Rectangle1.width, Rectangle1.height, "is",\
          Rectangle1.getArea())
```

It's easy to explain, why you receive this error: You defined the variable rectangle1, but in your print function call you want values of the object Rectangle1, which is not defined. Variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: def main():
        rectangle1 = Rectangle()
        print("The area of the Rectangle of radius" , rectangle1.width, rectangle1.height, "is",\
              rectangle1.getArea())
    main()

Okay so I've changed the cases but the error for some reason is still showing up.